# Having trouble with my API Request. Curl Method with 2 headers

Tags: json, swift, api, codable, urlsession

I would like some assistance trying to find out why I can't process this curl URLRequest in Swift.  I believe my issue is how I am adding my headers but I can't figure this out.  I've tried multiple ways without success.  All the examples I am finding here don't seem to work for this situation.

When I get to the JSONDecoder I think it's decoding something, but not what I am expecting and the debugger doesn't get to the catch error.

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated!

```
import Foundation
import SwiftUI

class Network: ObservableObject {
    @Published var Loan: [LoanSelected] = []
            
    func getLoan() {
        guard let url = URL(string: "https://absws.com/TmoAPI/v1/LSS.svc/GetLoan/1001")
        else
        {
            return
        }
        
        var urlRequest = URLRequest(url: url)
        let headers = [
            "Token": "VIC",
            "Database": "World"
        ]
        
        //urlRequest.httpMethod = "GET"
        //urlRequest.addValue("ABS", forHTTPHeaderField: "Token")
        //urlRequest.addValue("World Mortgage Company", forHTTPHeaderField: "Database")
        //urlRequest.httpBody = payload
        urlRequest.httpMethod = "GET"
        urlRequest.allHTTPHeaderFields = headers

        
        let dataTask = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: urlRequest) { (data, response, error) in
            if let error = error {
                print("Request error: ", error)
                return
            }
            
            guard let response = response as? HTTPURLResponse else { return }
            
            if response.statusCode == 200 {
                guard let data = data else { return }
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    do {
                        let decodedUsers = try JSONDecoder().decode([LoanSelected].self, from: data)
                        self.Loan = decodedUsers
                    } catch let error {
                        print("Error decoding: ", error)
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        
        dataTask.resume()
    }
}
```

Comment: It's not entirely clear how far your code gets. Does it reach the `if response.statusCode == 200 {` line? Is the status code 200? Is `data` non-nil? Does it get to the `JSONDecoder()` line? Use the debugger and step through the code and verify what really happens.

Comment: my apologies as this is my first attempt at XCode/SwiftUI.  after dataTask the error is nil.  Then error at the DispatchQueue becomes typeMismatch.  Data is 5191 bytes, but it doesn't look like any kind of real return of data.  It appears that it doesn't get to the JSONDecoder line either.

Comment: On your next questions, you give more infos: You have a working `cURL` (as the title suggests it), then share it with us, in case of request being wrong. You need to tell us what fails. It seems that `print("Error decoding: ", error)` is called, so share that output. It could be because `LoanSelected` is wrong (doesn't match the JSON, what's its definition), or because you have another kind of JSON/Response (due to bad request). Lastly, share what's returned: `print("Received: \(String(data: data, encoding: .utf8)")`. That's the full info that would have been needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not getting an array `[LoanSelected]` from the server with the url you show.

Try this approach, using model struts that **match** the json data you are getting from the API.

Here is my test code, works well for me.

Use https://app.quicktype.io/ to generate the correct model structs for you.

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @StateObject var network = Network()
    
    var body: some View {
        ScrollView {
            Text("Loan")
                .font(.title)
                .bold()
            
            VStack(alignment: .leading) {
                HStack(alignment:.top) {
                    Text("\(network.loan?.account ?? "no account")")
                    VStack(alignment: .leading) {
                        Text(network.loan?.bankName ?? "no bank").bold()
                    }
                }
                .frame(width: 300, alignment: .leading)
                .padding()
                .cornerRadius(20)
            }
        }
        .padding(.vertical)
        .onAppear {
            network.getLoan()
        }
    }
}

class Network: ObservableObject {
    @Published var loan: Loan?  // <-- here
    
    func getLoan() {
        guard let url = URL(string: "https://absws.com/TmoAPI/v1/LSS.svc/GetLoan/1001"),
              let payload = "".data(using: .utf8) else {
            return
        }
        
        var urlRequest = URLRequest(url: url)
        urlRequest.httpMethod = "GET"
        urlRequest.addValue("ABS", forHTTPHeaderField: "Token")
        urlRequest.addValue("World Mortgage Company", forHTTPHeaderField: "Database")
        urlRequest.httpBody = payload
        
        let dataTask = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: urlRequest) { (data, response, error) in
            if let error = error {
                print("Request error: ", error)
                return
            }

            guard let response = response as? HTTPURLResponse else { return }
            
            if response.statusCode == 200 {
                guard let data = data else { return }
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    do {
                        let decoded = try JSONDecoder().decode(ApiData.self, from: data) // <-- here
                        self.loan = decoded.data
                    } catch let error {
                        print("Error decoding: ", error)
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        dataTask.resume()
    }
}

struct ApiData: Codable {
    let data: Loan
    let errorMessage: String
    let errorNumber, status: Int

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case data = "Data"
        case errorMessage = "ErrorMessage"
        case errorNumber = "ErrorNumber"
        case status = "Status"
    }
}

struct Loan: Codable {
    let type, account, accountNumber, accountType: String
    let applyAs, bankAddress, bankName, borrowerRecID: String
    let byLastName: String?
    let cdfiReporting: String
    let coBorrowers: [String]
    let customFields: [CustomField]
    let debitAmount, debitDueDay, emailAddress, emailFormat: String
    let frequency, individualID, individualName, isTemplate: String
    let losLoanRecID, nextDebitDate, notes: String
    let primaryBorrower: PrimaryBorrower
    let primaryProperty: String?
    let recID, routingNumber, serviceStatus, sortName: String
    let stopDate: String
    let sysTimeStamp: String?
    let terms: [String: String?]
    let useDebitAmount, wpcPin, wpcPublish: String

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case type = "__type"
        case account = "Account"
        case accountNumber = "AccountNumber"
        case accountType = "AccountType"
        case applyAs = "ApplyAs"
        case bankAddress = "BankAddress"
        case bankName = "BankName"
        case borrowerRecID = "BorrowerRecID"
        case byLastName = "ByLastName"
        case cdfiReporting = "CDFIReporting"
        case coBorrowers = "CoBorrowers"
        case customFields = "CustomFields"
        case debitAmount = "DebitAmount"
        case debitDueDay = "DebitDueDay"
        case emailAddress = "EmailAddress"
        case emailFormat = "EmailFormat"
        case frequency = "Frequency"
        case individualID = "IndividualId"
        case individualName = "IndividualName"
        case isTemplate = "IsTemplate"
        case losLoanRecID = "LOSLoanRecID"
        case nextDebitDate = "NextDebitDate"
        case notes = "Notes"
        case primaryBorrower = "PrimaryBorrower"
        case primaryProperty = "PrimaryProperty"
        case recID = "RecID"
        case routingNumber = "RoutingNumber"
        case serviceStatus = "ServiceStatus"
        case sortName = "SortName"
        case stopDate = "StopDate"
        case sysTimeStamp = "SysTimeStamp"
        case terms = "Terms"
        case useDebitAmount = "UseDebitAmount"
        case wpcPin = "WPC_PIN"
        case wpcPublish = "WPC_Publish"
    }
}

struct CustomField: Codable {
    let name: String
    let tab: String
    let value: String

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case name = "Name"
        case tab = "Tab"
        case value = "Value"
    }
}

struct PrimaryBorrower: Codable {
    let account, borrowerRecID, city, deliveryOptions: String
    let emailAddress, emailFormat, firstName, fullName: String
    let lastName, mi, phoneCell, phoneFax: String
    let phoneHome, phoneWork, placeOnHold, recID: String
    let rolodexPrint, salutation, sendLateNotices, sendPaymentReceipt: String
    let sendPaymentStatement, state, street, tin: String
    let tinType, zipCode: String

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case account = "Account"
        case borrowerRecID = "BorrowerRecID"
        case city = "City"
        case deliveryOptions = "DeliveryOptions"
        case emailAddress = "EmailAddress"
        case emailFormat = "EmailFormat"
        case firstName = "FirstName"
        case fullName = "FullName"
        case lastName = "LastName"
        case mi = "MI"
        case phoneCell = "PhoneCell"
        case phoneFax = "PhoneFax"
        case phoneHome = "PhoneHome"
        case phoneWork = "PhoneWork"
        case placeOnHold = "PlaceOnHold"
        case recID = "RecID"
        case rolodexPrint = "RolodexPrint"
        case salutation = "Salutation"
        case sendLateNotices = "SendLateNotices"
        case sendPaymentReceipt = "SendPaymentReceipt"
        case sendPaymentStatement = "SendPaymentStatement"
        case state = "State"
        case street = "Street"
        case tin = "TIN"
        case tinType = "TINType"
        case zipCode = "ZipCode"
    }
}
```

Comment: Wow... the quicktype tool is very cool!  Must I include ALL items that are returned or can I only create structs for the items I am interested in?  For now, all is fine, I am just curious.  Right now, I am getting 'Cannot find 'ApiData' in scope for the JSONDecoder line.

Comment: no need for all the `fields`, just delete the ones you don't need. Regarding your error, it is due to your copy and paste mishap.

Comment: Yes, you are right... it was due to my copy/paste.  I used Struct instead of struct.  Thank you so much!

Comment: Thanks for the tick. Note, you may want this url `"https://absws.com/TmoAPI/v1/LSS.svc/GetLoans"`.
 In this case you need a different set of model structs, that give you an array of `[Loan]`. Add `print("\n---> data: \n \(String(data: data!, encoding: .utf8) as AnyObject) \n")` then copy and paste into https://app.quicktype.io/